# bash: Fastest way for echoing variables

Tags: bash

In bash, there are (at least) four ways to output variables:

```
    VAR=data

    echo "VAR:" $VAR
    echo "VAR:" ${VAR}
    echo "VAR: $VAR"
    echo "VAR: ${VAR}"
```

Which method is best (or best practice)? Or which method can be parsed/exectued the fastest by the bash shell?

Comment: Why not look into the [source code](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/)?

Comment: @devnull: Because source code tells you the "how", but neither the "what" nor the "why". You'd have to deduce it, and then hope that the next release doesn't invalidate your deductions.

Comment: Don't bother about performance, but do read up on variable quoting: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls

Comment: Best practice is the last one because it preserves spaces inside `$VAR`. The braces are unnecessary here, but using them everywhere doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is much of a performance difference, especially when compared to the overhead of actual I/O.

Comment: As for best practice, that's opinion, and thus I add it as a comment instead of making it part of the answer. I'd consider `"VAR: ${VAR}"` to be the best variation, as it is precise in syntax and intention. (Consider if the next character you'd print after `${VAR}` were an underscore: You would *need* the `{}` in that case, so make a habit of using it always.)

Answer (score 0):

None of them are recommended:

```
printf "VAR: %s\n" "$VAR"
```

How `echo` works can vary from shell to shell, while `printf` is a bit more standardized.